# How can I use an OR-condition in a Django ORM filter?

Tags: django, python-3.4, django-orm

Here is my django view:

```
    def get_initial_queryset(self):
    filter_dict={}

    location=self.request.POST.get('location_id')
    if location:
        set_if_not_none(filter_dict, 'port__device__host__location', location)
    client=self.request.POST.get('client')   
    if client:
        set_if_not_none(filter_dict, 'client__icontains', client)
    phone=self.request.POST.get('phone')    
    if phone:
        set_if_not_none(filter_dict, 'phone__icontains', phone)
    if line:
        set_if_not_none(filter_dict, 'line__icontains', phone)

    return Client.objects.filter(**filter_dict)
```

Here I need to make filter with OR condition like `where phone like %phone% or line like %phone%`
How can I do it with filter?

Answer (score 3):

See [Complex queries with `Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q). You need to write something like:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Client.objects.filter(Q(phone__icontains=phone) | Q(line__icontains=phone))
```

You can also build up the Q object like this:

```
filter = Q()
location = self.request.POST.get('location_id')
if location:
    filter = filter & Q(port__device__host__location=location)
client = self.request.POST.get('client')
if client:
    filter = filter & Q(client__icontains=client)
phone = self.request.POST.get('phone')
if phone:
    filter = filter & (Q(phone__icontains=phone) | Q(line__icontains=phone))
return Client.objects.filter(filter)
```